# ajax data post from pop up form not hitting the controller method ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a pop form `AddorEdit.cshtml`, which is called from `index.cshtml` page. The form is opening but unable to post data to controller method.

index page

```
// index.cshtml //
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddorEdit", "Vehicles")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a>
<table id="tbl_vehicle" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" >
//table block
<script>
function SubmitForm(form) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (date) {
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

pop up form

```
//AddorEdit.cshtml //

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddorEdit", "Vehicles", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
//form
```

controller method

```
// VehiclesController.cs //

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddorEdit([Bind(Include = "Id,VehicleType,Amount,RenewPeriod,Status")] Vehicle vehicle)
{

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (vehicle.Id <= 0)
            {
                vehicle.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
                vehicle.RegisteredBy = "admin";
                db.Vehicle.Add(vehicle);
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I am unable to detect why the data is not posting to the controller method. Thank You!!!

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your browser console or your event viewer?

Comment: Does the `form` instance in your `SubmitForm` method actually include the form details? Is the request sent to the proper action and with the proper details (either in QueryString or in Body)? If so, it should be an issue with the API endpoint not deserializing the values properly.

Comment: Does the ajax.success event fire? If you add a breakpoint to your action, does it hit? Also what value does form.action hold?

Comment: @nischalinn there is one mistake `success: function (date) {` change `date` to `data`. Then please test if your problem is solved or not. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
use like this in your Form,it will fix your problem

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddorEdit", "Vehicles", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = 
     "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
    {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
```

if you are using

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

this attribute on top of your action method
you must use

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

in your view